# Listen to imports or other requests originated from Deno server

Tags: javascript, deno

Lets say i have a module `qwe.js` and his content is following: `import('./asd.js')`

If i run this module somwhere from the client browser i can catch this `import` request on server side with `Deno.serveHttp` and generate some unique response even if file `asd.js` actually does not exist at all.

However if i run exact same module somewhere from the server im unable to make the same behaviour just becouse `import` statement goes uncatched with some built-in response logic.

Can i make so that my module with `import` would work identical both on client and server? Or in other words - can i listen/catch/intercept import requests originated from server to make custom responses for them?

Comment: can `import` in `Deno` use a url? can't see any other way to achieve it

Comment: The relevant GitHub issue is here: [denoland/deno#16555](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/16555)

Answer (score -1):

> My question was not about browser requests (i know how to handle them) but about requsts maded from server side, for example if you put some import in the first code block of your answer.

In general you can use [`inotify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

If the file exists you can use [`Deno.watchFs()`](https://deno.land/api@v1.41.3?s=Deno.watchFs).

Some of my recent file system observer experiments https://github.com/guest271314/fs, and some I did a while ago https://github.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio?tab=readme-ov-file#usage.

Comment: From your example i can see that you making 2 imports both from client side and catch them with HTTP server. My question was not about browser requests (i know how to handle them) but about requsts maded from server side, for example if you put some import in the first code block of your answer.

Comment: You can use something like `inotify`. If the file exists you can use `Deno.watchFs()`.

Comment: @ТоварищПонечка If the file really does not exists you can just use `catch()`chained to `import()` or `try..catch` to handle module not found error, then do stuff.

Comment: Again my question not in checking for file existance (it was just an example) but to intercept requsts originated from server to make custom responses for them. I want my modules to work identical both on client and server and so i want a tool similar to `Deno.serve` but for requests from server, just how it work for HTTP requests.

Comment: I made an issue in deno github https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/22982 maybe here its explained better.